# R: find relative weight within each group and within the entire dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr, frequency, tidyverse

My dataframe has one value in each row containing two other variables.

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- data_frame( car=c('A','A','A','B','B'), style=c('aa','bb','aa','aa','cc'), value=c(3,2,5,4,16) )

 car  style   value
 A     aa      3
 A     bb      2
 A     aa      5
 B     aa      4
 B     cc      16
```

How to find the relative weight for each style within each car group, and the relative weight for each style over all the data? Here is the desired output (# comments on the right not needed but added here for clarity showing the total weight calculations):

```
 car  style   value  style_for_car   style_total     # total value count is 30
 A     aa      3         0.80            0.40         # (3+5+4)/30 = 0.40
 A     bb      2         0.20            0.067        # 2/30 = 0.067            
 A     aa      5         0.80            0.40          
 B     aa      4         0.20            0.40
 B     cc     16         0.80            0.533
```

My attempt below only succeeds at calculating the total weight. How to get the desired output within the same dplyr pipeline:

```
df %>%
    group_by(style) %>%
    mutate( style_total = sum(value)/sum(.$value) )

     car  style   value   style_total
       A    aa     3       0.4000
       A    bb     2       0.0667
       A    aa     5       0.4000
       B    aa     4       0.4000
       B    cc    16       0.5333
```

Comment: Hacky, but something like `df %>% group_by(style, car) %>% mutate(style_for_car = sum(value) / sum(.$value[.$car == car])) %>% group_by(style) %>% mutate(style_total = sum(value) / sum(.$value))`, maybe

Comment: Can you fix your example? You have `6` in the 5th row in the construction of `df`, then `16` in the output.

Comment: Thanks @thelatemail! Done.

Comment: Also shouldn't rows 1 and 3 `style_for_car` be 0.80? Since `(3+5) / (3+5+2) = 0.8`

Comment: Yes, @thelatemail. I just corrected as I got your message. Sorry for the typos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ORIGINAL ANSWER- based on original question numbers

A couple of extra lines should do that `group_by(car)` and `mutate()` to compute `style_for_car` ...

```
df %>%
  group_by(car) %>%
  mutate(style_for_car = value / sum(value)) %>% 
  group_by(style) %>%
  mutate( style_total = sum(value) / sum(.$value)) 

#> Source: local data frame [5 x 5]
#> Groups: style [3]
#> 
#>     car style value style_for_car style_total
#>   <chr> <chr> <dbl>         <dbl>       <dbl>
#> 1     A    aa     3           0.3  0.40000000
#> 2     A    bb     2           0.2  0.06666667
#> 3     A    aa     5           0.5  0.40000000
#> 4     B    aa     4           0.2  0.40000000
#> 5     B    cc    16           0.8  0.53333333
```

UPDATED ANSWER - based on updated question numbers and comment re `.$`

@alistaire put a nice single-pipe solution in comments. To add, I'd be inclined to create separate data frames with relevant info, then join them to original data frame. This keeps code a little more readable (at least for me). Here's how I'd go about it (which also gets rid of `.$`):

```
# Create values for style_for_cars
df_cars <- df %>% 
             group_by(car, style) %>% 
             summarise(value = sum(value)) %>% 
             group_by(car) %>% 
             mutate(style_for_car = value / sum(value)) %>% 
             select(-value)
df_cars
#> Source: local data frame [4 x 3]
#> Groups: car [2]
#> 
#>     car style style_for_car
#>   <chr> <chr>         <dbl>
#> 1     A    aa           0.8
#> 2     A    bb           0.2
#> 3     B    aa           0.2
#> 4     B    cc           0.8

# Create values for style_total
df_total <- df %>%
              group_by(style) %>% 
              summarise(value = sum(value)) %>% 
              mutate(style_total = value / sum(value)) %>% 
              select(-value)
df_total
#> # A tibble: 3 × 2
#>   style style_total
#>   <chr>       <dbl>
#> 1    aa  0.40000000
#> 2    bb  0.06666667
#> 3    cc  0.53333333

# Join results
df %>%
  left_join(df_cars) %>% 
  left_join(df_total)
#> Joining, by = c("car", "style")
#> Joining, by = "style"
#> # A tibble: 5 × 5
#>     car style value style_for_car style_total
#>   <chr> <chr> <dbl>         <dbl>       <dbl>
#> 1     A    aa     3           0.8  0.40000000
#> 2     A    bb     2           0.2  0.06666667
#> 3     A    aa     5           0.8  0.40000000
#> 4     B    aa     4           0.2  0.40000000
#> 5     B    cc    16           0.8  0.53333333
```

Comment: It's essentially the same in `data.table` speak - `df[, style_total := sum(value) / sum(df[,value]), by=style][, style_car := value/sum(value), by=car]`

Comment: Wow, that does it! I know I originally used not so "tidyversy"  sum(.$value). Is there way to get rid off $?

Comment: @thelatemail I concur with your comments about weights, and re-corrected them! Simon Jackon's solution works for individual weights but not relative weights within each group

Comment: @Irakli You can get rid of the subsetting by adjusting the grouping more: `df %>% group_by(car, style) %>% mutate(subtotal = sum(value)) %>% group_by(car) %>% mutate(style_for_car = subtotal / sum(value)) %>% group_by(style) %>% mutate(style_total = sum(value)) %>% ungroup() %>% mutate(style_total = style_total / sum(value)) %>% select(-subtotal)`

Comment: @alistaire, that's some black-belt level piping!  I run each part and it's very clear. Love it! How can I mark it as a successful solution?

Comment: I've updated answer re a few comments (different values for `style_for_car` and removing `.$`)

Comment: If you use joins, you can use `count` and `prop.table` if you like: `df %>% left_join(df %>% count(car, style, wt = value) %>% mutate(style_for_car = prop.table(n)) %>% select(-n)) %>% left_join(df %>% count(style, wt = value) %>% mutate(style_total = prop.table(n)) %>% select(-n))`